# Issue with Babel preset 2015 and fat arrow functions

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

When I try to use a fat arrow function inside a class Component I receive the following error...

```
ERROR in ./src/app/components/Home.js
Module build failed: SyntaxError: C:/myproject/whole/src/app/components/Home.js: Missing class properties transform.
```

However, I have the proper packages in my package.json

For Babel

```
"babel-cli": "6.26.0",
"babel-core": "6.26.0",
"babel-loader": "7.1.2",
"babel-preset-env": "1.6.0",
"babel-preset-es2015": "6.24.1",
"babel-preset-es2017": "6.24.1",
"babel-preset-react": "6.24.1",
"babel-preset-stage-0": "6.24.1",
```

For Webpack

```
"webpack": "3.5.6",
"webpack-dev-server": "2.8.2",
"webpack-merge": "4.1.0",
"webpack-node-externals": "1.6.0"
```

And I´m setting the rule in Webpack for Babel

```
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.js?$/,
        loader: 'babel-loader',
        exclude: /node_modules/,
        options: {
          presets: [
            'react',
            'stage-0',
            ['env', { targets: { browsers: ['last 2 versions'] } }]
          ]
        }
      }
    ]
  }
```

Note: I also tried adding 'es2015' here before 'react'. Also, tried installing babel-plugin-transform-class-properties, creating the .babelrc conf file and adding there the plugin with no results.

And this is my component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';

class Home extends Component {

  consoleHi = () => {
    console.log('Hi');
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        Hello
        <div>{this.consoleHi()}</div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default Home;
```

If I transpile or use a "regular" function, it works.

```
  consoleHi() {
    console.log('Hi');
  }
```

What I´m missing?
Thanks and good weekend.

Remember that I´m learning =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try installing this plugin `babel-plugin-transform-class-properties`, then in your babel configuration, add `transform-class-properties` to the plugins array like so:

`{
  "plugins": [
    "transform-class-properties"
  ]
}`

Comment: Thanks a lot, Oreoluwa. I put it inside option and worked great. Much appreciated.